# How to use two different pages to see the post content?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have two tabs called  services and blog, and i have created the content of the pages with the help of post type. I want to show different single-page.php for services details and different single-page.php for blog details , How can i do that ?

Comment: Not 100% clear (are you displaying posts on Blog page) but you create separate page templates in one of several ways.  Most common is `page-{slug}.php for the distinct pages.  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Answer (score 0):

If they are separate post types you can use WP's theme file structure.
More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/